# cannot view calendar in HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, calendar, datepicker

I have a html table, which contains `startDate` and `endDate`. I want to show calendar to select date while clicking those text boxes.  Then we select a date from that calendar then the selected date will be display in that text box. I used the following code. But this is not working and not showing any errors. What is the problem with this code? What modification i need to do in this code? Or what is the best way to view a calendar view in those field?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://localhost/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/js/jqueryUI.js"></script>

<script> 
function calendar1(){
         $( "#startDate" ).datepicker();   
}
</script>

<table id='tblAppend' bgcolor='#D2DFEF'><col width='170'><col width='30'><tr><td>Portfolio Name:</td><td><input type='text' name='name'></td></tr>
<tr><td>start date</td><td><input type='text' name='startDate' onclick='calendar1();'/></td></tr>
<tr><td>start date</td><td><input type='text' name='endDate' onclick='calendar1();'/></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the UI's css.

Comment: added the css.but still it is not working.

Comment: Apart from that, you should try rajesh's answer - just call `$(selector).datepicker()` on DOM ready (`$(function(){});`) instead of those `onclick`s and you should be fine. Else check the JS console (F12 on Chrome or on Firefox with Firebug), the scripts may not be loading correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/3s6q4/)

HTML CODE

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="startDate" /></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="endtDate" /></p>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
 $(function () {
    $("#startDate , #endtDate").datepicker();
});
```